# vscode: how to remove the white highlight on the terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Here is a printscreen of the problem (with the inspect tool opened, on the right, in case it could help). As you can see in the setting (the file that is opened) the word "terminal" is only mentioned 2 times, and there is no background/highlight color mentioned with it.
[image: white background in vscode terminal]

EDIT: when I comment all my settings.json, it output this:
[image]
Any idea how to remove this annoying white background?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at this page, check the mentioned styles and see how they set this color? https://blog.codinghorror.com/is-your-ide-hot-or-not/

Comment: @xph thanks but I already know how to change the font and the (main) background but it doesnt solve the highlight issue which seems to be somehow inbuilt. ( `"terminal.foreground": "#00f35d", "terminal.background": "#3d4fec"`)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it (I guess so). In settings.json I needed to replace:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows":  "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

with this:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows":   "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe"
```

No idea why powershell causes this problem (bug?)